# Facebook all.js - Why am I getting this error in Safari: TypeError: 'null' is not an object

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am getting a Javascript error from the following file:

https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js

The error returned is:
TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating '///.*?(/[^#]*)/.exec(pa)[1]') on line 73

This only happens in Safari, and only when the page is in a Facebook app canvas.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was with my channel.html file. Docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/gettingstarted/) explain that the file "The channelUrl must be a fully qualified URL matching the page on which you include the SDK"

Once I had the channel.html file working Safari stopped complaining and my share popups worked...